# pivot and unpivot a table with multi columns in tsql

Tags: sql, t-sql, pivot-table

I need to pivot this table which looks like this:
[my current table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUAhE.jpg)
[image]

What I need is a table with 13 columns which looks like this:
[desired pivoted table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZkJk.png)
[image]

I'm using tsql in `RazorSQL`. Here is my code that resulted in the final table, which now needs to be pivoted. :

```
   select s5.datess, ISNULL(s5.Active_And_Good,0) AS Active_And_Good,  ISNULL(s5.Inactive_And_Good,0) AS Inactive_And_Good,
    ISNULL(s5.Active_And_Bad,0) AS Active_And_Bad, ISNULL(s6.Inactive_And_Bad,0) AS Inactive_And_Bad
            from
            (select s3.dates as datess, s3.#Active_Good as Active_And_Good,  s3.#Inactive_Good as Inactive_And_Good, 
    s4.Active_Bad as Active_And_Bad from
    (select s1.Dates as dates, s1.Active_Good as #Active_Good, s2.Inactive_Good as #Inactive_Good from
    (select count(DISTINCT Customer_Id) as Active_Good, Dates
    from #fact_table
    where Customer_Status = 1
    group by Dates) as s1
    full outer join
    (select count(DISTINCT Customer_Id) as Inactive_Good, Dates
    from #fact_table
    where Customer_Status = 2
    group by Dates) as s2
    on s1.Dates=s2.Dates)  as s3
    full outer join
    (select count(DISTINCT Customer_Id) as  Active_Bad, Dates
    from #fact_table
    where Customer_Status = 3
    group by Dates) as s4
    on s3.dates= s4.Dates) as s5
    full outer join
    (select count(DISTINCT Customer_Id) as Inactive_And_Bad, Dates
    from #fact_table
    where Customer_Status = 4
    group by Dates) as s6
    on s5.datess= s6.Dates ;
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work.  Tested on a cut-down version of your provided table.

```
Create table #test ([datess] date, [Active_AndGood] int, [Inactive_And_Good] int)
insert into #test ([datess],[Active_AndGood],[Inactive_And_Good])
values('2015-01-31',1,4) , ('2015-02-28',2,3)

select *
from #test
unpivot (value for name in ([Active_AndGood],[Inactive_And_Good])) up
pivot (max(value) for datess in ([2015-01-31],[2015-02-28])) p
```

Produces this:

[image]

Comment: No problem. ~:o)

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I need to Pivot or Unpivot, I take a look at these links to refresh my memory of how these kinds of things work.

https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/06/07/sql-server-pivot-and-unpivot-table-examples/

http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/t-sql-pivot-tables-in-sql-server-tutorial-with-examples.aspx

http://blog.jontav.com/post/8344518585/convert-rows-to-columns-columns-to-rows-in-sql

http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/understanding-sql-server-2000-pivot/

```
-- Creating Test Table
CREATE TABLE Product(Cust VARCHAR(25), Product VARCHAR(20), QTY INT)
GO
-- Inserting Data into Table
INSERT INTO Product(Cust, Product, QTY)
VALUES('KATE','VEG',2)
INSERT INTO Product(Cust, Product, QTY)
VALUES('KATE','SODA',6)
INSERT INTO Product(Cust, Product, QTY)
VALUES('KATE','MILK',1)
INSERT INTO Product(Cust, Product, QTY)
VALUES('KATE','BEER',12)
INSERT INTO Product(Cust, Product, QTY)
VALUES('FRED','MILK',3)
INSERT INTO Product(Cust, Product, QTY)
VALUES('FRED','BEER',24)
INSERT INTO Product(Cust, Product, QTY)
VALUES('KATE','VEG',3)
GO
-- Selecting and checking entires in table
SELECT *
FROM Product
GO
-- Pivot Table ordered by PRODUCT
SELECT PRODUCT, FRED, KATE
FROM (
SELECT CUST, PRODUCT, QTY
FROM Product) up
PIVOT (SUM(QTY) FOR CUST IN (FRED, KATE)) AS pvt
ORDER BY PRODUCT
GO
-- Pivot Table ordered by CUST
SELECT CUST, VEG, SODA, MILK, BEER, CHIPS
FROM (
SELECT CUST, PRODUCT, QTY
FROM Product) up
PIVOT (SUM(QTY) FOR PRODUCT IN (VEG, SODA, MILK, BEER, CHIPS)) AS pvt
ORDER BY CUST
GO
-- Unpivot Table ordered by CUST
SELECT CUST, PRODUCT, QTY
FROM
(
SELECT CUST, VEG, SODA, MILK, BEER, CHIPS
FROM (
SELECT CUST, PRODUCT, QTY
FROM Product) up
PIVOT
( SUM(QTY) FOR PRODUCT IN (VEG, SODA, MILK, BEER, CHIPS)) AS pvt) p
UNPIVOT
(QTY FOR PRODUCT IN (VEG, SODA, MILK, BEER, CHIPS)
) AS Unpvt
GO
-- Clean up database
DROP TABLE Product
GO
```

ResultSet:

```
-- Selecting and checking entires in table
Cust Product QTY
------------------------- -------------------- -----------
KATE VEG 2
KATE SODA 6
KATE MILK 1
KATE BEER 12
FRED MILK 3
FRED BEER 24
KATE VEG 3

-- Pivot Table ordered by PRODUCT
PRODUCT FRED KATE
-------------------- ----------- -----------
BEER 24 12
MILK 3 1
SODA NULL 6
VEG NULL 5

-- Pivot Table ordered by CUST
CUST VEG SODA MILK BEER CHIPS
------------------------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
FRED NULL NULL 3 24 NULL
KATE 5 6 1 12 NULL

-- Unpivot Table ordered by CUST
CUST PRODUCT QTY
------------------------- -------- -----------
FRED MILK 3
FRED BEER 24
KATE VEG 5
KATE SODA 6
KATE MILK 1
KATE BEER 12 12
```